# jquery- why value couldn't pass in ajax process

Tags: jquery

I'm creating a function that validates registration and sends it into a PHP script using Ajax, but it's only working half way - it's unable to send the username and password values through Ajax.

So, what's wrong with my Ajax function below?

```
function register(btregister)
{      
    username = $.trim($('#username').val());
    if (!validateUsername(username)) {  
        $('#username').focus();
        setTimeout(function() {$(btregister).removeAttr('disabled');}, 2000); 
        return;
    }

    password=$('#password').val();
    if (password == '') {
        $('#password').focus();
        setTimeout(function() {$(btregister).removeAttr('disabled');}, 2000); 
        return;
    }
      // it's stop working until here.

    $.ajax({ 
        type: 'POST',
        url: "http://localhost/system/controllers/ajax_register.php",
        data: 'un=' + username + '&pw=' + password,
        success: function(resp) {
            alert(resp);

        },
        error: function() {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Seem like okay with your code, could you also share html snippet ?

Comment: huhu,sorry,my fault, php file that I want to send has error  actually :)

Comment: I cleaned up the question at the start.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying your data as an object:

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: 'POST',
    url: "http://localhost/system/controllers/ajax_register.php",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: "{ 'un':'"+username+"', 'pw':'"+password+"' }",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(resp) {
        alert(resp);

    },
    failure: function() {

    }
});
```